# Error injecting factory to controller

Tags: angularjs, rest, angularjs-factory, angularjs-injector

If I don't inject `ValuesResource` into `welcomeCtrl` controller, application works. I had read error documentation, but can't find problem.

```
app.factory('ValuesResource', ['$resource',
function($resource) {
    return $resource('http://localhost:53257/api/Value/:id', { id: '@id' });
}]);

app.controller('welcomeCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$routeParams', 'ValuesResource',
    function ($scope, $rootScope, $routeParams, ValuesResource) {  

        $scope.getvalues = function() {
            $scope = ValuesResource.query();
        }

    }]);
```

**Error:**

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/unpr?p0=%24resourceProvider%20%3C-%20%24resource%20%3C-%20ValuesResource
at Error (native)
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:6:416
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:41:121
at Object.d [as get] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:39:92)
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:41:195
at d (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:39:92)
at Object.e [as invoke] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:39:362)
at Object.$get (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:37:311)
at Object.e [as invoke] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:39:394)
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:41:224 <div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">
```

Comment: is it an error on your factory?

Comment: @Sajeetharan Don't know I think not, but you can check it. I have posted it above.

Comment: Did you install ngResource properly?
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource

Comment: @Gatsbill No I don't have `ngResource`

Comment: Then you have to install it, $resource is not part of core angular

Comment: install ngResource library and inject with angular module e.g.

var app = angular.module('app', [ 'ngResource' ]);

Comment: Thanks, I had to add `ngResource`, it works now.